# Constructing a RootSum object changes existing internal syntax

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, bugs, replacement

**Bug introduced in 3.0 and persisting through 13.0.1, fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

I noticed that initially valid syntax becomes invalid within nested `RootSum` objects. Consider for example the expression

```
test=RootSum1[
  Function[{x},2 x^7 Log[5805]-(25 Log[5805]^6 RootSum[5805-696 #1+190 #1^2-8 #1^3+#1^4&,Log[#1]/(-2+#1)&]^2)/16384],
  Function[{x},(E^x (48 x^2 RootSum[5805-696 #1+190 #1^2-8 #1^3+#1^4&,(-11 Log[#1]-4 Log[#1] #1+Log[#1] #1^2)/(-174+95 #1-6 #1^2+#1^3)&]))/(64 x^3-48 x^2 Log[5805]+100 x RootSum[5805-696 #1+190 #1^2-8 #1^3+#1^4&,Log[#1]/(-2+#1)&]^2)]
]
```

Which is pretty valid expression where `RootSum` is replaced by `RootSum1` for demonstration. It contains two pure functions with valid syntax.

Now replace `RootSum1` by `RootSum`:

```
(test /. RootSum1 -> RootSum) // N
```

> (3.63594 + 0. I) RootSum[
> Function[{x}, {-32768. x^7 + 25. 48889.1 (0.416541 + 0. I)}],
> Function[{x}, {(
> 2.71828^x x)/((10.4135 + 0. I) - 103.998 x + 16. x^2)}]
> ]

Note that syntax for `Function` became invalid: additional internal `List` appeared, which prevents outer computation. With the internal list removed computations complete:

```
(3.63594 + 0. I) RootSum[
  Function[{x}, -32768. x^7 + 25. 48889.1 (0.416541 + 0. I)], 
  Function[{x}, (2.71828^x x)/((10.4135 + 0. I) - 103.998 x + 16. x^2)]
]

(* -0.283396 - 3.9421*10^-17 I *)
```

Is this a bug? Can it be avoided?

Comment: `(test // N) /. RootSum1 :> RootSum`

Comment: This is just a demo for a problem. I want exact result. Numerical evaluation is used simply to reveal the internal syntax change problem. Spent quite a while time to find what happens.

Comment: @BobHanlon Also, I dont' use Normal. This will replace RootSum to sum of Roots and will result in enormous expressions (the demo is a toy example). I want answer in nested RootSum objects, since they yield most compact symbolic expressions.

Comment: `test = RootSum[Function[{x}, 2 x^7 Log[5805] - (25 Log[5805]^6 RootSum[5805 - 696 #1 + 190 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, Log[#1]/(-2 + #1) &]^2)/16384], Function[{x}, (E^x (48 x^2 RootSum[5805 - 696 #1 + 190 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (-11 Log[#1] - 4 Log[#1] #1 + Log[#1] #1^2)/(-174 + 95 #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3) &]))/(64 x^3 - 48 x^2 Log[5805] + 100 x RootSum[5805 - 696 #1 + 190 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, Log[#1]/(-2 + #1) &]^2)]] /. List -> Sequence;`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. I agree this can be used as a bug fix.

Comment: Simpler buggy example: `RootSum[Function[{x}, 2 x^7 - 1], Function[{x}, (E^x) RootSum[10 - #1 &, Log] ]]`. Internally, the variable `x` is replaced by an internal variable, which near the end is replaced back by `{x}` instead of `x`. It seems to be a bug.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior in 9.0, 10.3, 12.0, and 12.1.1.  So it seems like an ancient bug that has only been discovered just now.

Comment: Confirmed in version 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRArR.png It's broken from the beginning. But it's fixed at least since version 13.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug does not exist for `Slot[1]`, just for `Function` with named parameters.  (A dummy variable is substituted for `x`, presumably so that the body of the `Function` may evaluate safely. When the dummy variable is replaced in the output, it is replaced by `{x}` instead of `x`).

In the OP's example, one approach would be to construct `RootSum` objects using `Slot[1]` instead of a named variable.

One can fix the OP's example as follows. Since none of the root sums inside a `Function[{x}, body]` contain an `x`, all the instances of `x` may be replaced by `Slot[1]` (`#`):

```
val = Hold[RootSum][
    Function[{x}, 
     2 x^7 Log[
        5805] - (25 Log[5805]^6 RootSum[
           5805 - 696 #1 + 190 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 
           Log[#1]/(-2 + #1) &]^2)/16384], 
    Function[{x}, (E^
         x (48 x^2 RootSum[
           5805 - 696 #1 + 190 #1^2 - 
             8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, (-11 Log[#1] - 4 Log[#1] #1 + 
               Log[#1] #1^2)/(-174 + 95 #1 - 
               6 #1^2 + #1^3) &]))/(64 x^3 - 48 x^2 Log[5805] + 
        100 x RootSum[5805 - 696 #1 + 190 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 
           Log[#1]/(-2 + #1) &]^2)]] /. 
   Verbatim[Function][{v_}, body_] :> (Evaluate[body /. v -> #] &) // 
  ReleaseHold

val // N
(*  -0.283396 - 3.9421*10^-18 I  *)
```

Hopefully that works in general (that `x` is free to be replaced by `#`).  One can use `Inactive[RootSum]` and `Activate` instead of `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`, if desired.

The bug does not appear every time `Function[{x}, body]` is used. There seems to have to be a `RootSum` in `body` and the other terms perhaps being `Listable`.

```
(* Bug *)
RootSum[Function[{x}, 2 x^7 - 1],
 Function[{x}, E^x RootSum[10 - #1 &, Log] ]]
(* No bug *)
RootSum[Function[{x}, 2 x^7 - 1], 
 Function[{x}, E^x Boole[x ∈ Complexes] RootSum[10 - #1 &, Log] ]]
RootSum[Function[{x}, 2 x^7 - 1], (* f undefined *)
 Function[{x}, f[x] + E^x RootSum[10 - #1 &, Log] ]]
RootSum[Function[{x}, 2 x^7 - 1], (* Internal RootSum = 0 *)
 Function[{x}, E^x RootSum[1 - #1 &, Log] ]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another workaround is not to put the single Function variable in a list.

```
In[1]:= test1=RootSum1[                                                         
  Function[x, 2 x^7 Log[5805]-(25 Log[5805]^6 RootSum[5805-696 #1+190 #1^2-8 #1^3+#1^4&,Log[#1]/(-2+#1)&]^2)/16384],                                            
  Function[x,(E^x (48 x^2 RootSum[5805-696 #1+190 #1^2-8 #1^3+#1^4&,(-11 Log[#1]-4 Log[#1] #1+Log[#1] #1^2)/(-174+95 #1-6 #1^2+#1^3)&]))/(64 x^3-48 x^2 Log[5805]+100 x RootSum[5805-696 #1+190 #1^2-8 #1^3+#1^4&,Log[#1]/(-2+#1)&]^2)]];                                                                              

In[2]:= (test1 /. RootSum1 -> RootSum) // N                                     

                              -17
Out[2]= -0.283396 - 2.60178 10    I
```

The bug is that the dummy variable gets replaced with the first argument of the input Function (even if the first argument was a list).